# UNIX How do I display .dot files following by other letter

Tags: unix

Encountering directory not found errors when I try to solve the following:

"Use metacharacters and the ls -lL command (with lower and upper case L) to list all filenames under the datafiles directory that contain a dot '.' with the letter 'f' or 'u' anywhere after the dot."

I enter the following and get directory not found errors:

ls -lL *.*[fu]

What step am I missing or command am I forgetting?

Comment: *"What step am I missing or command am I forgetting?"* - `ls -lL .*[fu]*`.  Or `man sh` :-)

Answer (score 1):

`.[fu]` searches for files/directories that match **exactly** - so it'll match the files/directories `.f` and `.u`, and **none others**.

You want `*.*[fu]*`, which matches anything which contains a dot, and at some point after contains an `f` or `u` (so `blah.af`, `foo.bau`, ...).

Comment: I'm still stumped, the directory I'm in is bin, I want to run a command from my current directory to search for files within a directory called 'datafiles' I basically want to type something such as .......  ls -lL datafiles *.*[fu]                 the purpose is to display files that first contain a "dot" character in its name, following by the letter f or u in it. Example files such as famous.backup and famous.data, will only look up famous.backup because it satisfies both the .dot and the f/u search.

Comment: @user8974164 [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48602914/edit) to include more information about your problem and what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved:
I overlooked an aspect on this.
Was forgetting to add the directory in the command. My answer turned out to be 
ls -lL datafiles/*.*[fu]*